# gnuplot on Mac OS X lion

Tags: macos, gnuplot

I've installed gnuplot using Mac Ports on a machine running Mac OS X 10.7. The installation exited without any errors or even warnings, however when I try to run it the following shows up:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libgd.2.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libgd.2.dylib requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libfontconfig.1.dylib provides version 6.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any suggestions what to do? Is there a quick and easy fix for such problems?

Comment: Check if you really have all the latest updates — the error message is quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNUPlot seems to work for me on Mac OS X v10.7.3 with an up-to-date MacPorts installation. I didn't have any plot files handy to open, but it launched okay.

Make sure your MacPorts environment is completely up-to-date:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

```
$ gnuplot

    G N U P L O T
    Version 4.4 patchlevel 4
    last modified November 2011
    System: Darwin 11.3.0

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2011
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help seeking-assistance"
    immediate help:   type "help"
    plot window:      hit 'h'

Terminal type set to 'aqua'
gnuplot> quit
```